# How can I make this update query work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following tables:

orientador:

[image: orientador]

importado:

[image: importado]

I' like to run the following query, updating `orientador.atividadeorientador` with it's respectivelly `importado.atividade`:

```
UPDATE importado
SET atividadeorientador = pco.atividade
FROM importado AS pci
  INNER JOIN orientador AS pco
      ON pco.codinst_o = pci.codinst
      AND pci.codigo = pco.codigo_o
      AND pci.codinst = 237
      AND pci.versao LIKE '002'
      AND pco.atividade > 0;
```

The result updates all the lines with a single value:

[image: result]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat the table being updated:

```
UPDATE importado pci
SET atividadeorientador = pco.atividade
FROM orientador pco
WHERE pco.codinst_o = pci.codinst AND
      pci.codigo = pco.codigo_o AND
      pci.codinst = 237 AND
      pci.versao LIKE '002' AND
      pco.atividade > 0;
```

Your version has two versions of `importado`, which Postgres interprets as a `CROSS JOIN` (this is different from the behavior in SQL Server).